# Why animate.css animation is played only once?

Tags: css, html, animation, animate.css

I am checking the navigator onLine property changes. To achieve this, we are listening to the HTML5 online/offline window events, so when we are in the offline mode, I play a flipInX animation, and the same thing when connection comes back I play a flipInY animation, in this case it works properly :

```
#yh-app.yh-online & {
    @include animation(flipInX 1s);
}

#yh-app.yh-offline & {
    @include animation(flipInY 1s);
}
```

The problem comes when i try to play the same animation for both (offline and online modes) for example flipInX for both:

```
#yh-app.yh-online & {
    @include animation(flipInX 1s);
}

#yh-app.yh-offline & {
    @include animation(flipInX 1s);
}
```

In this case the animation is played only once !!! 
Does anyone have solution, Please?
Thanks :)

Comment: If you want animation to be infinite - add `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`
in your css.

Comment: I don't want it to be played infinitely, just when i lose connection or when conenctin comes back, when i play 2 different animations, it works, when i just the same animation, it works only for the first time

Comment: Can you post what's in your `animation` mixin?

Comment: When lose connection add a class with `animation-iteration-count: infinite; `as suggested by @fen1x

Comment: i use github repo : animate-sass
FillInX : https://github.com/tgdev/animate-sass/blob/master/animations/flippers/_flipInX.scss
FillInY : https://github.com/tgdev/animate-sass/blob/master/animations/flippers/_flipInY.scss

Comment: Presumably the animation will not restart when the element's class changes, since it has already been applied. A couple of ideas: 1) Have two identical CSS animations, just with different names. Apply one to the offline state, the other to the online state. Not sure if that will work, but should be easy to test. 2) Follow the JS suggestion in this article https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/3o6fJ1C5K4uFRhk8Za

Comment: A follow up on my earlier suggestion. I can confirm that options 1 works: https://jsfiddle.net/rmp99qmo/ The solution involves duplicating CSS rules, which is icky, but perhaps it will suit your requirements.

Comment: @JonathanNicol, thanks you, but i try to avoid that, but do you have a explication why it works like that but not not with the same animation name?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work if you reapply the same animation twice is because you're asking the browser to do something it has done already. The browser thinks "meh, I already did that, I'm going to ignore you". Or something like that :D