# CSS Animations - How can I reverse an animation on a click event while allowing the animation to toggle back and forth freely?

Tags: css, css-animations

I've animated a hamburger icon to become an X using CSS animations. I want to reverse the animation using the `animation-direction` property. But if you look at the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/yb5pomLe/2/) you'll see that my attempt not only fails to smoothly reverse the animation, but also fails to play the forward animation again on the second click (js toggle).

How can I get this to animate smoothly?

```
.openUpArrowAnim .hamburger:nth-child(1) {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    height: .3em;
    background-color:white;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transform-origin: 25px -3px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 23px 7px;

    animation-name: crossBar1;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-direction: normal;
}

.openUpArrowAnim .hamburger:nth-child(2) {
   position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    height: .3em;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    animation: crossBar2 .5s ease .2s forwards;
}

.openUpArrowAnim .hamburger:nth-child(3) {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    height: .3em;
    background-color:white;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transform-origin: 25px -3px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 25px -3px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 25px -3px;
    animation: crossBar3 .5s ease forwards;
}

.openUpArrowRvrs .hamburger:nth-child(1){

    animation-name: crossBar1;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
.openUpArrowRvrs .hamburger:nth-child(2){
    animation: crossBar2 1s ease .2s reverse both;
}
.openUpArrowRvrs .hamburger:nth-child(3){
    animation: crossBar3 1s ease reverse forwards;       
}

@keyframes crossBar1{
    0% { transform: translateY(0px); }
    50% { transform: translateY(9px); }
    100% { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
}

@keyframes crossBar2{
    to {width: 0px;}
}

@keyframes crossBar3{
    0% { transform: translateY(0px); }
    50% { transform: translateY(-9px); }
    100% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can restart/reapply an animation by toggling a class. The browser thinks "meh, I already did that, I'm going to ignore you", or something like that.  See this article for a JS-based approach for restarting an animation: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/ Another way of doing it is to use multiple animations with different names. See my comments on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410458/why-animate-css-animation-is-played-only-once#comment81777338_47410458

Answer (score 0):

Animation is an overkill in this case. I'd use transitions. You can simply change the transform properties (and I recommend transitioning opacity for the middle bar to keep the animation running smoothly at 60fps), and when you remove the class, the properties are reverted and CSS applies its transition to smoothly animate it for you!

Your JS simply becomes a toggle:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("openAnim");
});
```

And your CSS becomes:

```
.btn .hamburger {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: .3em;
  background-color:white;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: transform ease-out 0.3s;
}

/**** Animation Default Arrow Up ****/
.btn .hamburger:first-child {
  transform-origin: 25px -3px;
  -ms-transform-origin:25px -3px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 23px 7px;
}

.btn .hamburger:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: opacity: ease-out 0.3s;
}

.btn .hamburger:last-child {
  transform-origin: 25px -3px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 25px -3px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 25px -3px;
}

/* Transition styles (replacing your keyframes) */

.openAnim .hamburger:first-child {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.openAnim .hamburger:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.openAnim .hamburger:last-child {
  transform: translateY(2px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/u5k3skzf/).